# Create Calendar Item Exchange 2010 Public Folder C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I want to create an appointment in a public folder with C#, in ASP.NET Web Forms

I'm finding very little information and examples.  Could someone point me to a simplified way to create a single appointment in an Exchange Public Folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the EWS Managed API you can create appointments within your Web Form. Here is a link to a "How to" topic for creating appointments that has come C# code you can work with:

[How to: Create appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495611%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

In order to save it to a public folder you will need to get the FolderId and use that when you do the `Appointment.Save()` method. There is some sample code to work with in this topic:

[How to: Work with folders by using EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535504%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem I have is how do I get this API?  In my project if I type in using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment Exchange is Underlined as not available.

Comment: Here is a link to the download page for this API: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022

Comment: So forgive me for my ignorance on this, I downloaded and installed that, but still Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment is underlined, I'm assuming because there is no reference.  How do I add the reference to it?  I looked under references, but it doesn't show up, do I have to browse somewhere for it?

Comment: I found it C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll